# Triggering another module export value (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project in ReactJS

In module A, I have a onClick events. the onClick event will do something in module A as well as trigger another module (call it Module B).
When Module B receive the event, it will generate a random number and it will export the var to other modules. However, I am not sure how to do it.

Here is my code

```
// Module A
somefunction(){
   generatingNumber();
}

//Module B
var number;
export function generatingNumber(){
  //do something to generate the number
  number = generatedNumber;
}
export var number

//Other Module
console.log(number)
```

the function is being run every time the the onClick event trigger, but the number never seems to change. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return your generatedNumber value from function.

```
// Module A
import {generatingNumber} from 'moduleB';
export function somefunction(){
   return generatingNumber();
}

//Module B
export function generatingNumber(){
  //do something to generate the number
  return generatedNumber;
}


//Other Module
import {somefunction} from 'moduleA';
console.log(somefunction()) // you get number here
or 
import {generatingNumber} from 'moduleB';
console.log(generatingNumber()) // you get number here
```

Answer (score 0):

Exports were not made for exporting dynamic variables.

Consider changing your module B to this:

```
//Module B
export function generatingNumber(number){
  newGeneratedNumber = number + 15; //do something to generate the number

  return newGeneratedNumber;
}
```